# can't download 0 bytes files via FTP

Tags: windows-10, ftp

As part of a website I've been working on these days, I wanted to download all its files from the hosting server via FTP.
Usually I use Filezilla for FTP transfers, which is working fine, and I was very surprised to find out that all 0-bytes files on the server failed to download to my local PC.
At first, I thought there's something wrong with FZ, but it happens also on WinSCP, CuteFTP and Core FTP LE.
When I try this action from another PC with a different connection, it works fine.
I came across a post in some forum, where the guy there said that after running the "CCleaner" on his PC, suddenly it started working again.
I tried that and after the first time I did the scan and the clean, it actually worked for me too. But that's it, the problem came back again at the second download attempt and this time the cleaning doesn't solve it anymore.
I have contacted the hosting company, of course, and they say that all the tests they did on their side for this issue came back successfully.
So, it is obviously something from my end and on this specific PC, but I just don't understand what exactly!
Why won't my PC download 0 bytes files from the server??
This also happens on all the hosting account I have on the same server and not on other servers I have similar accounts on. But again, the hosting company claims that their tests are successful, thus they have nothing they can "fix" on their side about this.
I do have ESET's Internet Security software installed and running on this PC, but I don't know if that started to happen right after this installation.
Anyway, I tried this also after temporarily disabling ESET's firewall.
I'm running a Windows 10 64-bit on this PC, with a fixed IP (not the cause).

Comment: What happens when you try to download a 0 byte file? Does filezilla show any errors? You could use wireshark to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Try downloading with Microsoft's web browser.  Try creating a zero byte file locally.  I suspect anti-virus software